# How to show an opened window in Android Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to manage some windows programmatically and I have a button for 'reopen' a previously opened window that's not the current one.

I want the 'android:back' button event to work so I don't close them, and when I call the .open method of an opened window in android, the titanium console says that cannot open an opened window.

The .show() method neither works.
Any ideas? I am totally newbie in Titanium, and I haven't found any responses in their forums.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? and it seems like you are asking multiple questions... and finally have you looked through or downloaded the kitchen Sink App and/or the TiBountyHunter app

Comment: I just want to focus an opened window, but I don't know how to accomplish this in titanium (android)

Comment: You can use the modal:true property of the windows and that can handle the navigation